# Ruby select top 3 groups by amount

Tags: ruby

I have an array and I need to group the array by name and then sum up the total for each group and then select the top 3 with highest amount per groups.

Here is my sample array

```
@transactions =
 [{"amount"=>-3000, "name"=>"CAR"},
 {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
 {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
 {"amount"=>-600, "name"=>"BOAT"},
 {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
 {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
 {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
 {"amount"=>-125, "name"=>"HOUSE" },
 {"amount"=>-6000, "name"=>"PLANE" }]
```

The response should be:

```
[PLANE, CAR, BOAT]
```

I currently have this but it does not work:

```
transactions.group_by { |trans| trans.fetch('name') }.map do |amount, transactions|
      [amount, transactions.map { |t| t[:amount] }.sum.abs.round(2)].select(3)
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question ask how to pick the 3 highest amount group names and the other question ask how to select one name based on number of occurrences and highest amount

Comment: Try to brake your problems into smaller steps. It not necessary to do it all on one line.

Comment: I can make a full answer here because the question was closed. So I made a GIst: https://gist.github.com/dquimper/4a4770a89a0d8997c74c810d0262bf32

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! @dquimper

Comment: I've voted to reopen because I do not consider this a duplicate of the earlier question, for the two reasons given by @SupremeA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a hash of the types (names), and sum the values as you go along with:

```
@transactions.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |obj, hash|
  hash[obj["name"]] += obj["amount"].abs
end
```

Then you can add some moar magic to the end of that, or break it up into more lines (recommended for readability):

```
@transactions.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |obj, hash|
  hash[obj["name"]] += obj["amount"].abs
end.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first).last(3).reverse
```

Basically, that's sorting by values (which turns your new hash to an array of tuples), then mapping the first value of each tuple (the name), then taking the top 3.

#### Edit

I didn't notice the negatives, so I summed while taking the absolute value of the amounts, then the sort_by sorts from smallest to largest, so take the *last* three and reverse to give you largest to smallest order.

It's a little complicated in a small block like that, I'd suggest breaking it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the amounts are always the same within each group(big assumption):

```
@transactions.group_by { |t| t["name"] }.
sort_by { |_, v| v.first.first.last.abs }.
take(3).
map(&:first)
 => ["HOUSE", "BOAT", "CAR"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def doit(trans, top_nbr)
  trans.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g["name"]] += g["amount"] }.
    min_by(top_nbr, &:last).map(&:first)
end

doit(@transactions, 3)
  #=> ["PLANE", "CAR", "BOAT"]

doit(@transactions, 99)
  #=> ["PLANE", "CAR", "BOAT", "HOUSE"]
```

Since only a few keys are to be returned, if the array of hashes is large, it's faster to use [Enumerable#min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by) than to sort the entire array. `min_by` was allowed to have an optional parameter in Ruby v2.2. (same for `Enumerable`'s `max_by`, `min` and `max`).